# Why is right setting for input type=text not working anymore?

Tags: css

2 weeks ago I wrote this part of html and css code looking like this and it worked fine as it should be:

```
<div class="divclass1">
    <input type="text" class="inputclass1" />
</div>

.divclass1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 26px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.inputclass1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px; 
    right: 0px;
}
```

The div was filled (checked it chrome) and so was the input field just like I wanted to be. Now, this week I was testing my unchanged html code again (or actually, I was testing some back end code, but that got nothing to do with this issue) and suddenly, the input field didn't filled to his parent div anymore but was on default width. It was just like the right: 0px didn't work together with the left: 0px, cause when I unchecked left: 0px; in chrome, the input field aligned to the right (but still not filled). Also, it wasn't only chrome where this issue is happening, as well did IE, FF, Opera. Only Safari was showing the input box like it should be.

I add a jsfiddle link to demonstrate the issue: fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/8ekbb/2/

I found a work around solution (which is also included in fiddle) but I really wonder if this issue is a bug and if so, will it be fixed again? Or is it working now like it should be and was the old it a bug that is fixed now?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use only or `right` or `left` in css and add `top` or `bottom` position if your element has `position:absolute` like this:

```
.divclass1 {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    height: 26px;
    background-color: blue;
    width:100%;
}

.inputclass1 {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0px;
    width:100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ekbb/5/)

Comment: But then it is only right aligned, not filled out to the width of the parent div which I want. (I want the same as the second div with the yellow background color)

Comment: update demo fiddle and answer, add width:100% try my new example DEMO please @Cornelis

Comment: Thank you. Although I figured that out too, see my second div. But I was really wondering why both left and right on 0px; isn't working anymore like it is still working in safari. But I must say, it starts to make more sense using left: 0px; (which is not needed anymore cause it is default) with width: 100% instead of (ab)using left: 0px; with right: 0px;

Comment: is a problem of browser of compatibility I think because in eery explainatio of position absolute is specified that you must use or left or roght t position well your element @Cornelis

Comment: Ah, okay. Then I guess it was a bug or some sort of thing. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, it's a general rule when you use an element in position.absolute you can't use top/bottom at the same time or right/left at the same time @Cornelis

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you for that lesson :) Although it was very handy to use both :)